# Pythonic way to resume after dealing with Exception

Tags: python, exception, resume

I have a script that is operating a physical device. There is a physical malfunction on the device that occurs sometimes and when it does, I want to reset the device and continue with the script. I have this:

```
while True:
    do_device_control()
    device_status = get_device_status()
    if device_status == 'Fault':
        reset_device()
```

It seems to me that a neater / more Pythonic approach would raise an Exception:

```
try:
    while True:
        do_device_control()
        device_status = get_device_status()
        if device_status == 'Fault':
            raise DeviceFaultException()

except DeviceFaultException:
    reset_device()
```

But as far as I can see, there is no way to resume the script after resetting the device. Is there a way to make Exception handling work for this situation, or a more Pythonic approach than what I'm currently using?

Comment: Raising an exception just to catch it yourself doesn't seem good to me. I'm not sure what the advantage is.

Comment: Why doesn't this work as written? I'm just curious as this seems to be correct to me without having to deal with exceptions, it should just continue running. Maybe add a time.sleep after the reset_device?

Comment: So, I think what you *want* is to put the `try-except` inside the loop. Again, though, your first example seems neater to me.

Comment: @metatoaster We don't know if the OP has access to the implementation of `do_device_control`.

Comment: The first version works. I thought that using exceptions was considered better practice, but maybe not?

Comment: No, not like this, i.e. raising it simply to catch it yourself. See the answer by @JamesMchugh for what it would look like using exceptions if you have control over the other functions.

Comment: By "yourself" we mean "within the same function". There is nothing wrong catching it in another function, even if you wrote them both.

Comment: As @juanpa.arrivillaga said, the first code block is acceptable if you have no control of the `do_some_control` function and cannot expect it to throw an exception if the device fails.

Comment: Did any of the answers resolve your question? If so, would you mind accepting the one that did. Not only does this allow you to give back to the answerers for taking the time to answer your question, but it also serves to better the SO community by showing users the correct resolution for the issue you faced. This can be a great asset for other users facing the same issue. If none of the answers solved your problem, can you add details to the closest answer so that it can be adjusted to fully answer it?

Answer (score 6):

A common Python idiom is "Ask forgiveness rather than permission", which applies very well to your question. An implementation like the following would suffice:

```
while True:
    try:
        do_device_control()
    except DeviceFaultException:
        reset_device()
```

This should get similar behavior as to what is in your original block of code using if statements.

However, you probably noticed that I did not check the `device_status` in my code. This is because you should allow the `do_device_control` function to raise the exception if it is unable to complete its task. This allows you to handle exceptions at the time the actions are being executed.

In an environment where you are working with a device that is running asynchronously to your code, you may check the device status and it be fine. It then might fail between the check and your `do_device_control` function. This is one example of why the "ask forgiveness rather than permission" paradigm exists.

Of course, this example only works if you can expect the `do_device_control` function to throw some sort of exception or change it so that it does. If you cannot expect/change this behavior, your first code block with the if statement would be preferred over explicitly raising an exception just to immediately catch it within the same code block.